# CodeIgniter email: fsockopen(): Unable to connect to ssl: //smtp.gmail.com in hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ssl

I use CodeIgniter email library to make the forgot password function. When I tried it on localhost all goes well no error. But when I moved to the hosting server error occurs like this:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1986

This my code:

```
$ci = get_instance();
        $ci->load->library('email');
        $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
        $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
        $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
        $config['smtp_user'] = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
        $config['smtp_pass'] = "xxxxxxx";
        $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
        $config['mailtype'] = "html";
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

        $ci->email->initialize($config);
```

What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable SSL.
Load php.ini and find a line with the following:

`;extension=php_openssl.dll`

Uncomment by removing the semicolon:

`extension=php_openssl.dll`

That has worked for me